# ApplicationEventPublisher NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, oop, dependency-injection

I have a next customEventPublisher-class:

```
@Component
public class CustomEventPublisher {

@Autowired
private static ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

public static void doStuffAndPublishAnEvent(User user) {
    OnPostUserDataEvent onPostUserDataEvent = new OnPostUserDataEvent(user, REST_URL);
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(onPostUserDataEvent);
   }
 }
```

publishEvent-method invoked in Service:

```
 public User create(User user) {

    CustomEventPublisher.doStuffAndPublishAnEvent(user);

    return repository.save(user);
}
```

config:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="example.service"/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="example.util.emailUtil"/>
```

Event is realised in:

```
public class OnPostUserDataEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String appUrl;

private User user;

public OnPostUserDataEvent(User user, String appUrl) {
    super(user);
    this.user = user;
    this.appUrl = appUrl;
    }
}
```

And I catch NullPointedException for:

```
 applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(onPostUserDataEvent)
```

Maybe ApplicationEventPublisher is not bein @Autowired, but I can't understand why.

Comment: `@Autowired` doesn't work on static, and there's no reason for anything in your publisher to be static. Use constructor injection and a non-static field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're fighting AOP. `doStuffAndPublishAnEvent` method is static, so it is not invoked on an instance, where `ApplicationEventPublisher` can be injected.

To overcome this, you would have to make `doStuffAndPublishAnEvent` non-static and inject `CustomEventPublisher` to your service, so that you can call the method on proxy over the instance.